# Processing IAsyncOperation<..> for reflected class in UWP

Tags: c#, reflection, async-await

For obvious reasons it makes sense to obfuscate all references to classes, methods and properties from `Windows.Services.Store`, namespace.

The troubles are caused by async methods. Consider, for example the following code:

```
var info =  await context.GetAppLicenseAsync();
```

Since the method returns `IAsyncOperation<StoreAppLicense>`, it can be obfuscated as the following:

```
string mehtodName=decode("Obfuscated Name"); // Returns "GetAppLicenseAsync"
var info = await (IAsyncOperation<StoreAppLicense>)
       context.GetType().GetRuntimeMethod(methodName, new Type[0]).
             Invoke(context, new object[0]);
```

However class StoreAppLicense is still used in cast and I can't find a way to obfuscate it. As far as I know, C# generic doesn't allow "any class" (similar to `<?>` in Java), while `IAsyncOperation<object>` gives a InvalidCastException.

There is away to create (generic) type  `IAsyncOperation<StoreAppLicense>`, but how can I cast to it? This forum and some others have pages for casting to reflected type, but some provide methods (like Convert.ChangeType or Type.TryCast) which are unavailable with UWP, the others effectively suggest to avoid cast. I can't see a way to avoid cast in case of async method, as  it actually returns a generic com object which can't be used without a cast. Suprisingly Type class has method `IsAssignableFrom`,  but no method `Assign`. Any ideas?

Comment: And how this obfuscation is going with regular classes? If this method was not async - what would be the difference?

Comment: There is a difference: you just cast "normally" without exposing any class, specific to this namespace.

Comment: So you mean without async info variable would be of type object and in this sense won't "expose" AppStoreLicense class?